# Can't share program files folder w10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, network-shares, shared-folders

I'm trying to execute a program that is installated in a computer, in another computer of the same safe LAN.

For that, I disabled the sharing with password protection, and then proced to share the C whole drive. The problem is that I can't access "Program Files" folder from the "remote" computer, w10 says I don't have permission.

But I can't change permissions of the program files folder from the "source" computer, even being and administrator. Everything is greyed and I can't change anything.

What I can do?

Best regards.

Comment: You may alter the owner of "Program Files" folder, of course - but I do not recommend it strongly. You may easily damage your OS. Make a copy of your app folder in separate location (in Common documents, for example) and provide access to it for remote user. PS. The program started by such way remotely may fail to start, because of it needs in some additional components/files installed and/or registry keys created, or it uses some hardcoded paths.

Comment: I have already changed the owner from trustedInstaller to adminsitrator, but still can't change permissions.

Comment: I use a different, neutral folder (not Program Files, not Windows and not Users) to share information. Such a neutral folder can easily be shared to other users. I do this myself.

Comment: Ok, because what are the main risks of changing "program files" owner?

Comment: Removing restrictions on Program Folder permissions can open you to viruses and malware and subsequent outcomes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to change any permissions on Program Files, since that can cause
problems that might require to reinstall Windows.

I instead suggest the opposite solution - bring your files to the other computer by
doing:

- Create a share on your computer that externalizes the files for that program
- Use Remote Desktop to login to the computer and run the program on your files.

This has a much better chance of working, since the remote program might not
function well on your computer where it was never installed and might not have
available the environment that it requires.

Answer (score 0):

try with this
...
right button..option propierties
tab security
button edit
button agree
advanced option
button find
on the find results lock...
netowrk...and agree.. and accept...
this mode assign right for acces a this file en program files
greetings

Answer (score -1):

This link shows you how to do this:

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer

And this link also has a bit more information:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3dd0d2f9-5b2f-46df-950f-36887c98369c/give-full-permission-for-the-users-in-program-files-folder?forum=w7itprogeneral

Not recommended to do this unless its your only option, there are specific permissions set on Program files to proctect your computer from viruses. There is more information of the security of this here:

https://www.samlogic.net/articles/installation-program-windows-vista-7.htm